# Android weightsum not working as expected

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have one horizontal Linear Layout with Width = match_parent and weightsum=5.
If i insert 5 vertical Linear Layouts with each width=0 and weight=1 everything looks as expected, the layouts each get the same width.
If i add only 2 vertical with each width=0 and weight=1 they take more space than they should. I expected them to also take 1/5 of the space.

Maybe it is the correct behaviour that they take more space and I understood the concept of weight/weightsum wrong.

Thanks for any help!

edit:
I try to add some Code

```js
LinearLayout linear=null;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

linear=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
              linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
              linear.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
              linear.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 10);
              linear.setWeightSum(Float.valueOf(modulo));
//modulo 5 in my example


LinearLayout linear2=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
if(count%modulo!=modulo-1){
        lp1.setMargins(0, 0, 15, 0);
} else {
        lp1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
       }
linear2.setLayoutParams(lp1);
linear2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

I add the layout linear 2 into linear in a loop
Why can you click run code :D

Comment: Could you also post a screenshot?

Comment: this is not possible with layout weight attribute. With layout weight, the views are all equal and fills up the place.

Comment: But i set weightsum to 5 and weight of the layouts to 1 so they should all take 1/5 of the space?

Comment: WeightSum works Properly when you initialize your layout to Fill_PARENT. I can see in your code,l you have intialized your linear layout with height WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: But I use the weight for the width, why would the height influence the outcome?

Comment: Hmm... weightsum should work as you expect. So it should be somewhere else in your code. Also it could be a bug. Do you able to reproduce it for other devices/platforms? In that case you can try to use LinearLayourCompat from support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logical solution does not work fill the rest with

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"/> <!-- or whatever the rest is -->
```

or

```
View space = new View(this); // NEVER CREATE VIEWS WITH APP CONTEXT!
LinearLayout.LayoutParams spaceParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 3f);
linear.addView(space, spaceParams);
```

NOTE: `Space` widget didn't work in this case.

Comment: I replaced all the Appcontexts with this. The space thing does not work either, always the same outcome :(

Comment: Hmm.. First try height of `1` (it's the second layout params parameter), if that doesn't work try `View` instead of `Space`, if that doesn't work try both combined, if that doesn't work... In any case let me know.

Comment: So if i use a View except for a Space with weight 3 it works. I dont really like such "workarounds" but at least it does wha I want. Thank you very much for your help. If you edit your answer i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5">
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can weightSum used in height?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5">
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="Your bg"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="Your bg"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

divide weight equally.